# Listing yum group

Tags: linux, installation, package, yum

When I run `yum grouplist` in a Red Hat environment and I received the following groups under the ***Available Groups*** list.

How do I find out that which packages are contain in a specific group (e.g 'Development Tools')? I would like to install specific packages and not a whole group (especially if I am not sure what is in the group).

```
$ yum grouplist

    Available Groups:
       DNS Name Server
       Development Tools
       Engineering and Scientific
       FTP Server
       Games and Entertainment
       Graphics
       Java Development
       KDE (K Desktop Environment)
       KDE Software Development
       MySQL Database
       News Server
       PostgreSQL Database
       Sound and Video
       Web Server
       Windows File Server
```

Answer (score 37):

Try `yum groupinfo`

From the groupinfo section of the manpage:

> Is used to give the description and package list of a group (and which type those packages are marked as). Note that you can use the yum-filter-data and yum-list-data plugins  to  get/use  the  data  the other  way  around (Ie. what groups own packages need updating). If you pass the -v option, to enable  verbose mode, then the package names are matched against installed/available packages similar to  the list command.

Comment: Is there also a way to list the RPMs associated with those? That would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

In latest Fedora (20), this has changed to

```
yum group info "core"
```