# List all packages in yum group

Tags: linux, centos, yum

How do I view the list of packages available in a yum group?

For instance, what is included in "Development tools"?

```
yum groupinstall "Development tools"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listing yum group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239543/listing-yum-group)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
yum groupinfo "Development tools"
```

Comment: Thanks Ignacio,  Yes that is what I was looking for.  Is it possible to tell what version of a package is included.  Probably the same.

Comment: Group information does not include package version information.

Comment: `yum groups info -v "Development tools"` will show the package version information too